# How to do reverse EXTRACTJSONFIELD function?

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

Format my records in topic - `key: 1-2MDWE7JT`, I want to convert it into `key: {"some_id" : "1-2MDWE7JT"}`.
How can I include a field into json with ksql functions? I didn't find a reverse function for "EXTRACTJSONFIELD" like "INCLUDEJSONFIELD".

Comment: You'd need to create a Struct field then let the stream format handle the JSON conversion

Answer (score 0):

If the data is written as `key: 1-2MDWE7JT` in the input topic, you can only *read* it this way, ie, the schema would a plain `VARCHAR` type. You could wrap the key into a `STRUCT` dynamically at query time though

```sql
SELECT STRUCT(f1 := v1, f2 := v2) FROM s1;
```

Cf https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/ksqldb-reference/select-pull-query/#struct-output

Thus, you would create an output STREAM that contains the key wrapped as like you want if (if you use JSON key format).